# Data Abaixo do grafico

Tags: r

Ola, tenho o seguinte código[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

minha duvida é, usando a função legend tem como eu colocar as datas abaixo do gráfico?
se não, qual seria a melhor forma para fazer isso?

Comment: A melhor opção é `axis(1, at = onde, labels = o_quê)`.

Comment: MrLops, bom dia! Não utilize imagem com código, existe um bloco onde você pode inserir seu código formatado dentro da propria pergunta. Abraço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja a ajuda para `barplot`, ela possui um argumento para fornecer os nomes das barras:

```
# Dados de exemplo
set.seed(757)
dados <- data.frame(date = paste(2020, 1:8, sep = "-"), cases = rpois(8, 4))

with(dados, barplot(cases, names.arg = date))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]